# How to create a product details slider on post?

Tags: custom-post-types

I am using WordPress. I have to display the product details slider on each post with different details.

For example, I have `apple` post and I have to add a product slider so my slider details are

```
Product_title   price  desc  link        image
iPhone x       $650   xyz   textt.com   1.jpg
iPhone 7       $550   abc   textt.com   2.jpg
iPhone 6s      $450   pqr   textt.com   3.jpg
```

**These details will not display on another post.**

What I am thinking there are two options

1) Create custom post type and add information then create a shortcode and add shortcode to the post.

2) Create the `Gutenberg` block and add details.

I need to know which is the best and easy? Till now I am not using any plugin. I have created a 30 post.

I am trying to add below fields and once the user clicks on `add more` then the same filed will display again and can add next details.

[image]

Below is the code for the above fields. I refer this link https://jeremyhixon.com/tool/wordpress-meta-box-generator/ to generate the fields.

**Note: add more button is not working.**

```
function product_details_get_meta( $value ) {
    global $post;

    $field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $value, true );
    if ( ! empty( $field ) ) {
        return is_array( $field ) ? stripslashes_deep( $field ) : stripslashes( wp_kses_decode_entities( $field ) );
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function product_details_add_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'product_details-product-details',
        __( 'Product details', 'product_details' ),
        'product_details_html',
        'productslider',
        'normal',
        'default'
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'product_details_add_meta_box' );

function product_details_html( $post) {
    wp_nonce_field( '_product_details_nonce', 'product_details_nonce' ); ?>

    <p>
        <label for="product_details_product_title"><?php _e( 'Product title', 'product_details' ); ?></label><br>
        <input type="text" name="product_details_product_title" id="product_details_product_title" value="<?php echo product_details_get_meta( 'product_details_product_title' ); ?>">
    </p>    <p>
        <label for="product_details_product_price"><?php _e( 'Product price', 'product_details' ); ?></label><br>
        <input type="text" name="product_details_product_price" id="product_details_product_price" value="<?php echo product_details_get_meta( 'product_details_product_price' ); ?>">
    </p>    <p>
        <label for="product_details_product_description"><?php _e( 'Product description', 'product_details' ); ?></label><br>
        <textarea name="product_details_product_description" id="product_details_product_description" ><?php echo product_details_get_meta( 'product_details_product_description' ); ?></textarea>

    </p>    <p>
        <label for="product_details_product_link"><?php _e( 'Product link', 'product_details' ); ?></label><br>
        <input type="text" name="product_details_product_link" id="product_details_product_link" value="<?php echo product_details_get_meta( 'product_details_product_link' ); ?>">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="product_details_product_img"><?php _e( 'Product image', 'product_details' ); ?></label><br>
        <input type="file" name="product_details_product_img" id="product_details_product_img" value="<?php echo product_details_get_meta( 'product_details_product_img' ); ?>">
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="product_details_submit" id="product_details_submit" value="Add More">
    </p>

<?php
}

function product_details_save( $post_id ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['product_details_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['product_details_nonce'], '_product_details_nonce' ) ) return;
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) return;

    if ( isset( $_POST['product_details_product_title'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'product_details_product_title', esc_attr( $_POST['product_details_product_title'] ) );
    if ( isset( $_POST['product_details_product_price'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'product_details_product_price', esc_attr( $_POST['product_details_product_price'] ) );
    if ( isset( $_POST['product_details_product_description'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'product_details_product_description', esc_attr( $_POST['product_details_product_description'] ) );
    if ( isset( $_POST['product_details_product_link'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'product_details_product_link', esc_attr( $_POST['product_details_product_link'] ) );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'product_details_save' );
```

Comment: If you're using WooCommerce, check out WooCommerce Blocks. They have a product block that will let you display multiple products. You might need to look into how it's built and build your own to include the additional details, but that would be a solid long-term solution. You might also check what other add-ons and plugins are available - it's likely someone else has had a similar need and you could buy something out of the box.

Comment: @WebElaine, No I am not using the WooCommerce plugin.

Comment: Either way building a block would be a longer-term solution than a shortcode. However, which is "easier" depends on whether you have more skills in PHP or JS. A shortcode is created with PHP while blocks typically require JS skills.